# how to render data from postgresql to csv in python flask app?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new in python and trying to write a code in it. I am trying to run a select query but i am not able to to render a data to csv file ?

this is the psql query :

```
# \copy (
# SELECT
# sr.imei,
# sensors.label,sr.created_at,
# sr.received_at,
# sr.type_id,
#
```

but How to write it in python to render it to csv file ?

thanking you,
Vikas

Comment: Hi. You should start by reading some online tutorials on how to access postgresql with python. Try to implement the steps in the tutorials available online. If you then get stuck with a specific problem, feel free to ask. As is, this question is too broad/no MVCE/no attempt to answer. You may also want to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM sensor_readings WHERE reading=blahblahblah) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ';'"
with open("/tmp/sensor_readings.csv", "w") as file:
    cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
```

I think you just need to change the sql for your use, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Install `psycopg2` via `pip install psycopg2` than you need something like this

```
import csv
import psycopg2

query = """
        SELECT
        sr.imei,
        sensors.label,sr.created_at,
        sr.received_at,
        sr.type_id,
        sr.data FROM sensor_readings as sr LEFT JOIN sensors on sr.imei = sensors.imei
        WHERE sr.imei not like 'test%' AND sr.created_at > '2019-02-01'
        ORDER BY sr.received_at desc
    """

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="routing_template", user="postgres", host="localhost", password="xxxx")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)

cur.close()

conn.close()
```